# Test not wrapping in wrapfig

Tags: geometry, wrapfigure, books, wrapfig

Working on a book writing project for a friend. I am using the wrapfig environment to wrap my text around the figure as I have done in the past, but there is something in the geometry of the page that is not wrapping the text at all. Ideas?

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=8in,paperwidth=8in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=\parindent, labelindent=\parindent}


\begin{document}
\section{Rulebook: Mercenarium}

For 2-4 players. Average game time: 30 minutes.\\

{\bf Components:}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item[(1)] (71)-card Anthromancer Deck
\item[(1)] (4) quick reference cards (one for each player)
\item[(2)] 6-sided dice (the blue Fool die and the purple Fox die)
\item[(1)] 12-sided Zodiac die
\item[(1)] Anthromancer board
\end{itemize}

{\bf Set up:}\\

\

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{1-1.png}
\caption{The Board: Houses and player seating}
\end{wrapfigure}

{\bf House Placement:} Open your game board and place it face up on a sturdy, flat surface. On the board there are colored circles in the center space along each board edge that are either Red, Orange, Yellow, or Green, and have a small black emblem in their center. These spaces are called {\bf houses} and each player will be in control of one during the game. Have each player sit at the house that they will control. In 2-player games, players should sit directly across from each other.

{\bf NOTE:} The center space has no special gameplay function in Mercenarium.

\end{document}
```

Here is what I get:

[image: Page Render]

Comment: note `\bf` isn't defined by default in latex, but use `\mbox{}{\bf House Placement:}` so that the paragraph does not start in a group (also the `\\ ` at the ends of paragraphs are wring and cause warnings about badness1000 and bad spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=8in,paperwidth=8in,
            margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=\parindent, labelindent=\parindent}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\section{Rulebook: Mercenarium}

For 2-4 players. Average game time: 30 minutes.\\

{\bf Components:} % this is TeX notation, in LaTeX must be \textbf{...}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item[(1)] (71)-card Anthromancer Deck
\item[(1)] (4) quick reference cards (one for each player)
\item[(2)] 6-sided dice (the blue Fool die and the purple Fox die)
\item[(1)] 12-sided Zodiac die
\item[(1)] Anthromancer board
\end{itemize}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1-1.png}
\caption{The Board: Houses and player seating}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Set up:}\\[\baselineskip]
%
\textbf{House Placement:} Open your game board and place it face up on a sturdy, flat surface. On the board there are colored circles in the center space along each board edge that are either Red, Orange, Yellow, or Green, and have a small black emblem in their center. These spaces are called {\bf houses} and each player will be in control of one during the game. Have each player sit at the house that they will control. In 2-player games, players should sit directly across from each other.\\[\baselineskip]
%
\textbf{NOTE:} The center space has no special gameplay function in Mercenarium.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The critical factor was starting paragraphs with {\bf...} instead of \textbf{...}.

Comment: Thank you for finding this! I forgot that this is crucial for setting up paragraphs and "gluing" them together. Saweet!